# SQL query stalls the system when connecting through python

Tags: python, sql, jdbc-odbc

My data is too big and it's around 19M and it takes too long to execute this query. So, I introduced chunks but still, I am not sure if this is the right way to do it. Is there a way to read large datasets to data frames from SQL? Could someone please help?

```
import os
import jaydebeapi as dbdriver
from socket import gethostname
import jaydebeapi as dbdriver
import pandas as pd

servername = xxxx
port = "9999"
db = "dev"
uid = xxx
password = xx

path = "documents/idea.jar"
client_hostname = gethostname()
user_agent = "%s-%s" %(dbdriver>__name__.client_hostname)

conn_uri = ""
cnxn = dbdriver.connect("")

table ='harn'

dfl = []
# Create empty dataframe
dfs = pd.DataFrame()
my_queries = ["select * from" + table" CONTEXT ('querytimeout' = 0)"]
for chunk in pd.read_sql(myqueries, con=cnxx, ,chunksize=10000000):
    # Start Appending Data Chunks from SQL Result set into List
    dfl.append(chunk)
# Start appending data from list to dataframe
dfs = pd.concat(dfl, ignore_index=True)
    dfs .to_csv(tables.csv)
cnxn.close()
```

Comment: https://dask.org/ - has very similar methods to pandas, works using parallel processing and clustering - Needs a slightly different approach in that calculations are only made when calling the .compute() function.  Will take some time to refactor

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you're filling your RAM memory saving (even if chunk by chunk) all the 19M records in a list. If you don't need to serve all the data in the same moment, you can think about serving only the chunk is needed in that moment.

Comment: i have 500gib memory

Comment: I would like to get a CSV file for doing a machine learning model. That way I can replicate results.